# How can I import class from base.py in __init__.py in django 3.0. It seems it isn't able to set self.apps_ready while app registry

Tags: python, django

Django Version - 3.0

BaseModel - base_models/models.py

```
# Create your models here.

from django.db import models


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

base_models/__init__.py

```
from base_models.models import BaseModel
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...,
     'base_models.apps.BaseModelsConfig',
     ...
]
```

**Error** -

> File "/Users/vaibhavsharma/vaibhav/workspace/rm-api/rm-api/base_models/__init__.py", line 1, in 
>       from base_models.models import BaseModel
>     File "/Users/vaibhavsharma/vaibhav/workspace/rm-api/rm-api/base_models/models.py", line 6, in 
>       class BaseModel(models.Model):
>     File "/Users/vaibhavsharma/vaibhav/workspace/rm-api/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 107, in **new**
>       app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
>     File "/Users/vaibhavsharma/vaibhav/workspace/rm-api/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
>       self.check_apps_ready()
>     File "/Users/vaibhavsharma/vaibhav/workspace/rm-api/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
>       raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
>   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: That is correct, you should import it in the `ready` method of the app configuration. Why exactly do you want to import this in the `__init__.py`?

Comment: Hey @WillemVanOnsem , thanks, yes it's working fine but I was thinking of using something like 

`from base_models import BaseClass?` is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, you cannot do that in Django 3.0. It seems like in this version on every app initialization self.check_apps_ready() function runs from apps/registry.py that itself checks from the INSTALLED_APPS from app/settings.py.

So here's how I used my BaseModel.

1. python manage.py startapp **base**.
2. deleted models.py file from **base** app
3. created **models** directory in the same app.
4. created the **__init__.py** file in **base/models/**.
5. Initialised my models in **base.py**.
6. Included the **BaseModel** in **init**.py(base/models/__init__.py) by
   `from .base import BaseModel`
7. Finally in base/__init__.py include `from .models import BaseModel`
8. Include BaseModel anywhere in the app by `from base import BaseModel`.

done!

Reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package